# Drupal 7 -> Media File Selector -> alt attributes on images

Tags: image, drupal, alt

I have read several questions that deal with this issue, but the answers are more parallel to my question than right on the mark. Please feel free to correct any assumption below that is incorrect.

POINT 1: In what I have seen in Drupal 7, there are a couple of options for widgets in the image field type
 - image
 - media file selector (which requires some extra modules)

POINT 2: The Media File Selector allows images to be reused from an image already uploaded. The plain image widget doesn't, resulting in an image having to be re-uploaded for each time it is used.

POINT 3: The plain image widget has the possibility of allowing alt tags to be added to an image. The Media File Selector doesn't.

QUESTION: Is there a way to get both benefits: 1) re-using the images, 2) alt tags on the images

Answer (score 1):

Media 1 and 2 allow you to share the uploading of images between file/image fields on entities... and even via the WYSIWYG.
Media 2 allows the addition of images alt and title tags.  As of now I do not consider it 100% production ready though.
For allowing alt and title tags on image/file fields on entities using media 1 follow these instructions:

http://nextentity.com.au/blog/2013/apr/adding-alt-tag-title-tag-support-media-1x-existing-drupal-7-sites

Just remember that when creating your fields use the 'image' field type, with the 'media file selector' widget.

I hope this helps.